# How to correctly implement my own exception handler in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I´m moving from C# to C++ so forgive me if the question is basic or has some misconceptions...

I want to build my own exception to be used on my try/catch blocks. I need to report a custom exception code, a custom exception message and a custom exception source origin - I may have all or some of these parameters.

So I´ve built that class:

**CommonException.hpp**

```
namespace exceptionhelper
{

    class CommonException : public std::exception {

    public:
        CommonException();
        CommonException(std::string message);
        CommonException(std::string source, std::string message);
        CommonException(int code, std::string source, std::string message);
        virtual ~CommonException();
        const char *what() const throw();


    private:
        int exceptionCode;
        std::string exceptionSource;
        std::string exceptionMessage;
    };

}
```

And the implementation:

**CommonException.cpp**

```
namespace exceptionhelper {
        CommonException::CommonException() {
            exceptionCode = 0;
            exceptionMessage = "No message.";
            exceptionSource = "No source.";
        }
        CommonException::CommonException(std::string message) {
            exceptionCode = 0;
            exceptionMessage = message;
            exceptionSource = "No source.";
        }
        CommonException::CommonException(std::string source, std::string message) {
            exceptionCode = 0;
            exceptionMessage = message;
            exceptionSource = source;
        }
        CommonException::CommonException(int code, std::string source, std::string message) {
            exceptionCode = code;
            exceptionMessage = message;
            exceptionSource = source;
        }
        CommonException::~CommonException() {
        }
        const char *CommonException::what() const throw()
        {
            std::stringstream s;
            s << "Code    : " << exceptionCode << std::endl;
            s << "Source  : " << exceptionSource << std::endl;
            s << "Message : " << exceptionMessage << std::endl;
            return s.str().c_str();
        }
    }
```

And finally my implementation:

```
main ()
{
   try {
        ... code ...

        throw new CommonException(10, "here", "test exception");

   }
   catch (const std::exception &exc)
   {
            std::cerr << "Exception detected:" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << exc.what();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cerr << "Unknown exception called." << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
}
```

For some reason I´m getting this result:

```
Unknown exception called.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'linuxcommon::exceptionhelper::CommonException*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Questions:

a) Why am I not catching my custom exception ?
b) I´m pretty sure there are better ways to do this exception handling, but I cannot figure that out yet...

Thanks for helping...

Comment: `new` returns a pointer. You don't need to use it here. You hardly ever need to call `new` in C++.

Comment: I.e. you're throwing a `CommonException *` and catching a `std::exception &`. One is a pointer, the other a reference. Climb out of the C# box and drink from the C++ fountain. Lose the `new`. Then fix the string problem Alex describes below.

Comment: Well, well... I´m relly drinking from the C++ fountain, but my body seens to be refusing it... Removing the new solved the problem! Thanks for helping!

Comment: `return s.str().c_str();` is not right.  You're returning a buffer associated with a temporary variable associated with a local stream.  All of them are going away before the function returns.  This error is called "RETURNING A DANGLING POINTER".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes for your code.

1. You may want to derive your exception class from `std::runtime_error` (instead of `std::exception`), since `std::runtime_error` already provides a constructor with an error message string.
   Of course you can add your own exception's data members to the derived class.
2. You don't need to define a virtual destructor with an empty body for your exception class, since you don't have explicit cleanup code to execute. `std::exception` has a virtual destructor, and that will work just fine for your derived exception class.
3. You can use a more idiomatic C++ syntax to initialize your exception data members in constructors, e.g. instead of:

> ```
> CommonException::CommonException() {
>     exceptionCode = 0;
>     exceptionMessage = "No message.";
>     exceptionSource = "No source.";
> }
> ```

you can use:

```
CommonException::CommonException()
  : exceptionCode(0), 
    exceptionMessage("No message."), 
    exceptionSource("No source.")
{ }
```

4. If you pass string parameters, you can still pass by value, but you may want to `std::move()` from the value to initialize data members, e.g. instead of:

> ```
> CommonException::CommonException(std::string source, std::string message) {
>     exceptionCode = 0;
>     exceptionMessage = message;
>     exceptionSource = source;
> }
> ```

You can do:

```
CommonException::CommonException(std::string source, std::string message) 
    : exceptionCode(0),
      exceptionMessage(std::move(message)),
      exceptionSource(std::move(source))
{
}
```

5. Consider making your single-string-argument constructor `explicit`, to prevent bogus implicit conversions from strings to exceptions:

   ```
   explicit CommonException(std::string message);
   ```
6. In its current form, your `what()` method implementation can throw, because inserting operations (`<<`) on `std::stringstream` can throw:

> ```
> const char *CommonException::what() const throw()
> {
>     std::stringstream s;
>     s << "Code    : " + exceptionCode << std::endl;
>     s << "Source  : " + exceptionSource << std::endl;
>     s << "Message : " + exceptionMessage << std::endl;
>     return s.str().c_str();
> }
> ```

So, remove the `throw()` specification, making it simply:

```
const char* CommonException::what() const
```

(As a side note, the modern C++11 way of marking a method as non-throwing is using `noexcept`).

You may also want to simply use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` to avoid premature pessimization.

Moreover, you are returning in this line a *temporary* string:

> ```
>  return s.str().c_str();
> ```

The `const char*` pointer returned to the caller will just point to some garbage at the call site: this introduces a bug.

To fix that, you may want to consider adding a `std::string` data member, format the whole error message string inside that data member during exception object construction (i.e. in your constructors - you may also build a private helper method to do that, to avoid repeating code in each constructor), and just return `m_str.c_str()` from the `what()` method.

If you derive your exception class from `std::runtime_error`, you can just build the whole error message string at construction time, and pass that to `std::runtime_error`'s constructor. In this case, `std::runtime_error::what()` will Do The Right Thing, and you won't need to override `what()` in your exception class.

E.g.

```
// Derive from std::runtime_error instead of std::exception
class CommonException : public std::runtime_error

...

CommonException::CommonException( /* your exception data */ )
    : std::runtime_error(BuildErrorMessage( /* your exception data */ )
{ }

// Private helper method
std::string CommonException::BuildErrorMessage( /* your exception data */ )
{
    // Build your exception message string here,
    // e.g. you can use std::ostringstream here,
    // and just call its str() method
    // to return the whole error message string.
    ...
}
```

---

At the exception's "client" side, you have:

> ```
>   ... code ...
>
>     throw new CommonException(10, "here", "test exception");
>
> }
> catch (const std::exception &exc)
> ```

Instead, consider throwing **by value**, instead of dynamically allocating the exception object on the heap, e.g. simply do:

```
throw CommonException( /* your exception data*/ );
```

Comment: i think taking in const ref to string ctor would be better

Comment: @Sarang: In general, if you are _observing_ an object that is not cheap to copy (like a `std::string`), using const reference would be fine. But in case of making a **local copy** (e.g. in a data member), passing by value and moving from the value is a better approach, considering C++11 move semantics.

Comment: Mr.C64, why the `std::move` ?

Comment: @Mendez: You may want to search about techniques involving C++11 parameter passing. [This thread on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10472179/1629821) is a good starting point.

Comment: All fine, but the code does not allow me to remove the `throw()` on `what`... error: `looser throw specifier for virtual const char* CommonException::what() const`

Comment: If you follow my suggestion and derive your exception class from `std::runtime_error()`, you don't need to override and reimplement `what()`. You should also remove `throw()` from both the declaration of the method (in the header file) and from the definition (in the .cpp file). Moreover, I think if you really want to override `what()`, assuming your error message was formatted in a `std::string m_errorMsg` data member, `return m_errorMsg.c_str();` from `what()` should be fine.

Comment: @Mr.C64: how are the two approaches different? The second approach seems to be using the new move semantics- but otherwise both create a copy (either you are calling a copy ctor or move ctor)